# awk: delete the first column and add four columns after the last one

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with data represented as:

```
32446191    0   5   5   2014-06-27  13210
62357877    18  89  89  2014-06-27  13210
33879626    81  1   1   2014-06-27  13210
```

Actually I have about 30 columns. I need to delete the first column (and the separator) and add four columns after the last one. Then the result would like:

```
0   5   5   2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
18  89  89  2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
81  1   1   2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
```

How to do it in awk with one command? Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving the original spacing:

```
$ awk -v OFS='   ' '{sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); print $0, 0, 0, 0, 0}' file
0   5   5   2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
18  89  89  2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
81  1   1   2014-06-27  13210   0   0   0   0
```

Tweak `OFS` to suit.

Comment: Thanks Ed, your solution is better than mine:

`awk -F '\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=1)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' $file`
`awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}{$(NF+1)=$(NF+2)=$(NF+3)=$(NF+4)=0; print}' $file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf("%-4s%-4s%-4s%-12s%-5s  0  0  0  0\n",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) printf("%-4s ", $i); printf "  0  0  0  0\n"} file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the columns with the extra 0's and use `column -t`:

```
awk '{ print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, 0, 0, 0, 0 }' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
0   5   5   2014-06-27  13210  0  0  0  0
18  89  89  2014-06-27  13210  0  0  0  0
81  1   1   2014-06-27  13210  0  0  0  0
```

For custom columns:

```
awk -v columns='2 3 4 5 6' 'BEGIN { l = split(columns, c); } { t = $c[1]; for (i = 2; i <= l; ++i) t = t OFS $c[i]; print t, 0, 0, 0, 0; t = "" }' file
```

Modify `OFS`, use `printf`, or simply use `column -t` for the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just update the question to make it clear.
Actually I have many fields. Do you have another approach?

Comment: @Daniel It's not possible to have a uniform column output format with awk alone unless the length of those columns are definite.